# Information for swapping tiles in a gridview

Tags: android, gridview

i'm making an n-puzzle and already have a gridview with one blank image in the bottom-corner in the right. My goal is now to shuffle the images in the gridview and make a game of fifteen. As  beginning programmer in android i have little knowledge of the platform and would apreciate tips and tricks or hints of how i must handle this problem.

I already know that the .setTag() command will be very handy for this problem, but can't seem to find informationblogs or sources on how to use it properly and how to handle this problem.

with kind regards,

Kees Til